# Формат файла подготовленный для печати

Tags: xml, pdf, печать

Всем Привет!

Разрабатываю прогу для генерирования документов. В документах графики нет (но желательно предусмотреть логотипы), только текст и таблица. Раньше доки были в xls, были эксперименты с xml с шаблоном из Excel, но хочется уйти от зависимости ))
PDF не подходит - бинарный формат, хочется типа xml или json.

Можно даже в том же html/mht, но каждый браузер по своему напечатает да ещё и с колонтитулами.

У кого какие идеи? ))

Comment: Уточните что за прога-это серверное решение или win приложение? Если win, то на каком языке Вы пишите и какой редактор используете, может Вам подскажут какие компоненты использовать!

Comment: Пишу на Питоне, реализация подойдёт, в принципе, любая, лишь бы сама этого позволяла. Соответственно, буду крутиться исходя из предложенных решений ))

В идеале: нужна программа, которая выполняет точную печать из файла с текстовой разметкой. Есть такой XPS - но его знает только Windows 7, но как знать, может его взять на вооружение, но я его мало тестил. Есть формат PDF - печатается очень правдоподобно, но бинарный - придётся использовать различные конвертеры, да и вручную подправить "на лету" pdf уже не удастся.

Comment: В общем, наткнулся на http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL-FO
буду рыть, мысль интересная, была бы хорошей реализация ))

Answer (score 1):

> PDF не подходит - бинарный формат

Это нет так.

- [TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)
- [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript)
- [Python graphics package](http://pyx.sourceforge.net/)
- [Python PostScript Generator](http://www.nongnu.org/pypsg/)
- [Ответы с SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177799/)

Comment: Я ваше двустишие совершенно не понял, но за ссылки спасибо ))
интересные вещи, хоть весь день сегодня и рою инет, они мне не попадались!

Answer (score 0):

Ну ведь можно же сделать вывод на html, который подойдет для всех браузеров. Вообще, если хочется уйти от зависимостей разных программ, типа PDF и Excel, то htm, по моему, лучший выход.
Ну а про какие колонтитулы идет речь, если в параметрах печати их можно отключить. А как xml Вы напечатаете? Или тот же json? Это же просто форма представления данных. И я более чем уверен, что есть уже готовые решения для вывода документов в разные форматы, в том числе кроссбраузерный html.

Comment: Видите те ли, html - сплошной, в нём нет разделения листа (по крайней мере, я о таком не знаю). XML я печатал в Excel'е - в нём была ссылка на экселевский шаблон xsl - очень удобно, когда данные хранятся в одном файле (или в базе данных), а форматирование в шаблоне, этим и привлекателен XML ))

Comment: Да, колонтитулы можно отключить, это могу сделать я, но, если это потребуется сделать другому человеку...
Хотелось бы, чтобы работало всё без настроек из под коробки ))

Comment: ХА! Ну если у вас уже есть удобная система, то зачем же ее переделывать-то??? В универе один гениальный преподаватель постоянно учил, что не надо выбрасывать то, что уже сделано, а намного более рационально - просто улучшить существующее. Тем более, где видано, что у кого-то и где-то проблемы с тем, что нет Excel? Вообще, в любом случае, просматривать документа надо будет при помощи чего-то. Даже если вам придется свою программу создать для просмотра особых ваших файлов.

Comment: Даже если захотите переделать заново, то, думаю, Word тоже неплохо подойдет. Там и форматирование всего текста вместе с колонтитулами можно задать на этапе создания документа. И все-все смогут им пользоваться. Ну, на этом мои идеи закончились. Может, кто еще что-нить посоветует.

Comment: Ворд хорош в плане оформления, но он не хавает XML, и в него не вставить формулы, как в Экселе

Comment: Ексель-то у всех, но не у всех он лицензионный /
Обратил было внимание на Стартер 2010, но этот пакет, как оказалось, через несколько дней без инета просто уже не запустится, а у нас на работе даже и сейчас есть такие места, где нет инета ))

Answer (score 0):

Разберитесь с форматом ".doc": стандарт все таки. В нем уже продумано все, что вам нужно, и без велосипедов.